# PHP scrape website that uses JS to put content AFTER

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to scrape the following website for price
https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/product/15489111/Bicicleta-Titanium-700C-Verde/15489114
Usually that could be done by using PHP file_get_contents() and finding and html element and selecting innet text, but it appears this website in particular uses JS to generate HTML after.
What can be done? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no option to scrape JS websites using PHP, but you can use libraries for testing. For example https://github.com/symfony/panther

Answer (score 0):

Not using PHP to scrape it. You need a framework with embedded browser like https://phantomjs.org/.

You actually need to run the JS that's on the page. There's no other way.